# How do I  avoid public folder name from zend framework project URL?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am a newbie with Zend framework. How do I run the url of project without the public folder name.I am using a shared hosting server .Anyway to change this by using .htacces ?.
I should have the url look like myzfproject.mydomain.com.
Please advise me

Comment: What does this have to do with Zend?  Simple DNS and http daemon configuration solves this for you.

Comment: @Brad Can you explain a little bit more ? You mean I need to point the url  to the public folder ?

Comment: How can I?  You didn't say what web server you are using, nor DNS.  I can't explain anything for you, if you can't explain what software you are using.

Comment: @Brad Thanks.I will check this with server people ,they may have help me. FYI ,I am using linux server hosted on znet

Comment: You're using cPanel.  Depending on how this is setup, usually you just go and click "subdomains" and add one.  In any case, this is no longer appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Voting to migrate it to ServerFault.com.  Please read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Brad .Thought I should get a answer with adjusting the .htacces file or index.php so.

Comment: You thought wrong.  This has nothing to do with .htaccess or index.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to point the site document root to the project's `public` directory.

If you are using CPanel (as mentioned in the comments), you can simply add the `myzfproject` sub-domain and enter the directory to the `public` directory (relative to your home dir) in the Document Root field (ref http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/SubDomains#Add%20a%20Subdomain).

Another option is to completely separate the `public` folder from the rest of the application.

For example, the contents of the `public` folder can reside anywhere, say `/home/user/sites/myzfproject` which is set as the site document root.

The application can exist anywhere else, say `/home/user/apps/myzfproject` with the `application` and `library` folders within.

The only change required would be to `/home/user/sites/myzfproject/index.php`

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', '/home/user/apps/myzfproject/application'));
```

Comment: @RintoGeorge: "Thanks Phil for your advise" [*sic.*] is best expressed "[by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.](http://serverfault.com/faq#howtoask)".